# how to extract first appearing of specific word in a column

Tags: r, extract

I would like to extract first occurrence of specific words in a column. So basically, I have a column like this.

```
product
Jasjus Mangga & Diabet Sweetener
Krimer Thai Tea 20s & Jasjus Madu 
[FREE TUMBLER] Susu Platinum 
Buy 2 Get 1 Free Krimer Thai Tea
```

Basically I want to extract first occurence of several words like 'Jasjus', 'Krimer', 'Diabet' and 'Susu'. SO then, I could make one more column consists of those words.

```
product                              brand
Jasjus Mangga & Diabet Sweetener     Jasjus
Krimer Thai Tea 20s & Jasjus Madu    Krimer
[FREE TUMBLER] Susu Platinum         Susu
Buy 2 Get 1 Free Krimer Thai Tea     Krimer
```

I know how to extract the words which is located besides special characters like '/' and '&', but I didn't find the way how to extract the first occurrence word. Thanx so much before.

Comment: The question can be solved like this but it would still be kind to provide [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_extract` after pasting the pattern together

```
words <- paste0(c('Jasjus', 'Krimer', 'Diabet' ,'Susu'), collapse = "|")
df$brand <- stringr::str_extract(df$product, words)

df
#                            product  brand
#1  Jasjus Mangga & Diabet Sweetener Jasjus
#2 Krimer Thai Tea 20s & Jasjus Madu Krimer
#3      [FREE TUMBLER] Susu Platinum   Susu
#4  Buy 2 Get 1 Free Krimer Thai Tea Krimer
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(product = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("[FREE TUMBLER] Susu Platinum", 
"Buy 2 Get 1 Free Krimer Thai Tea", "Jasjus Mangga & Diabet Sweetener", 
"Krimer Thai Tea 20s & Jasjus Madu"), class = "factor")), row.names = 
c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: if i want to neglect the lower and upper case of the brand words, i just add code like this? Is it right?
words <- paste0(c('Jasjus', 'Krimer', 'Diabet' ,'Susu'), collapse = "|",ignore.case=T)
df$brand <- stringr::str_extract(df$product, words)

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto In that case, you can do `str_extract(df$product, regex(words, ignore_case = TRUE))`

Comment: Thanx so much before mate :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R` methods

```
df$brand <- regmatches(df$product, regexpr(paste(c('Jasjus', 'Krimer', 'Diabet' 
       ,'Susu'), collapse = "|"), df$product))
df$brand
#[1] "Jasjus" "Krimer" "Susu"   "Krimer"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(product = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("[FREE TUMBLER] Susu Platinum", 
"Buy 2 Get 1 Free Krimer Thai Tea", "Jasjus Mangga & Diabet Sweetener", 
"Krimer Thai Tea 20s & Jasjus Madu"), class = "factor")), row.names = 
c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```